# entire function with some properties

Tags: complex-analysis

suppose that $f$ is an entire function such that $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(1+1/n)=7-3/n$ for all $n$ natural number. we have to find all $f$ that satisfies these properties.

What I have done is: define $g(z)=f''(z)-10+3z$, so $g(1+1/n)=0$ so uniqueness theorem implies that $f''(z)=10-3z$ and therefore  $f'(z)=10z-3z^2/2 +a$, As $f'(0)=0$ so $f(z)=5z^2-z^3/2+b(constant)$ is my solution is correct?

Comment: What is the uniqueness theorem?

Comment: if zero set has limit point in the domain of the analytic function then it is identically zero there.

Comment: I think you meant $f''(z)=10-3z$.

Comment: ah yes u r right...

Comment: OK, I have edited in the correction for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is correct: since the equality $f''(z)=10-3z$ holds on a set with a limit point, it holds for all $z\in\mathbb C$. By integration, using the condition $f'(0)=0$ it follows that $f(z)=5z^2-z^3/2+\text{const}$.